# Generate pom.xml in jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, pom.xml

I want to generate with IntelliJ/Gradle a jar with a `pom.xml` inside in order to use it in another project.
I tried the following code for `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar {
    into("META-INF/maven/$project.group/$project.name") {
        from generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
        rename ".*", "pom.xml"
    }
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901.jdbc4'
}
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
'jar' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.closure <org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask> )'
```

And gradle says:

```
Could not find property 'generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication' on
task ':jar'.
```

Or does someone know another method?

Comment: What is `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication`? It seems that it causes problem..

Comment: Maybe you should use the `maven-deploy` Gradle plugin for this?

Comment: The `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication` is a task from gradle listed in `publishing` which creates the pom.xml in the `build` directory

Comment: How do you want to use jar in another project?

Comment: @Alex78191 With `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file -Dfile=somejar-built-with-gradle.jar`. I use this during a multi-stage Bamboo build where one stage packages a jar with gradle and next stage then compiles with maven using the jar.

Answer (score 4):

The task `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication` is created late during the configuration phase. You will have to defer the creation of the reference to the task by assigning the task as `Closure` return type in the from statement.

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

jar {
    into("META-INF/maven/$project.group/$project.name") {
        from { generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication }
        rename ".*", "pom.xml"
    }
}
```

from [Github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1278#issuecomment-276681405)

Comment: This worked for me with 2 notable differences: 1) no need for the `publishing.publications` section 2) had to rename `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication` to `generatePomFileForPluginMavenPublication` (gradle 4.10.3 here)

Comment: @Alex do you need `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`?

Comment: Yes, certainly, otherwise `generatePomFileForPluginMavenPublication` won't be found. Note that instead of `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`, I am using `plugins { id 'maven-publish' }` as per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block

Comment: correction: `generatePomFileForPluginMavenPublication` is provided from `java-gradle-plugin`, and not from `maven-publish`. `maven-publishing` provides `publishing {}`. I'm using `java-gradle-plugin` instead of `java` because I'm building code for a gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1):

`from` wants a file or path.  What you're feeding it, `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication` is a task, which is most definitely not a file or path, so that's not going to work.

What you can do is make `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication` a prerequisite for `jar` and pick up the pom it creates in your build directory.

Something like the following should accomplish this:

```
jar {
    dependsOn generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
    from("$builddir/pom.xml") //Or whatever path it goes to in the generate task.
    into("META-INF/maven/$project.group/$project.name")
}
```

Comment: It seems that gradle cannot fin the task generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication (i edited my question, found another error message from gradle)

Answer (score -1):

I just found out that the `pom.xml` doesn't have to be inside the jar.

It works when I publish to Maven Local (and not Maven Central):

```
group 'ch.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901.jdbc4'
}
```